# export table using ssh

Tags: mysql

I want to export a table of mysql database using ssh so how can I take this one.

Answer (score 4):

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname tablename >dump_table.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

- Export the table to a file, using [MySQLDump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), [PHPMyAdmin](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export#SQL) or your favorite tool.
- Transfer the file to the host of your liking, using [scp](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scp) or your favorite tool.

What do you mean "export using SSH?" SSH is a protocol to securely talk to a server. SCP is a way to copy files between hosts using SSH, so I assume you mean that.

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name >dumpfile
scp dumpfile 127.0.0.1:.
```

If you dislike mysqldump, you can always just SELECT INTO OUTFILE from your favorite MySQL client (or PHP program, or just the commandline `mysql`). After that you transfer the file to the other host, and run LOAD DATA INFILE to load the table. You'll have to recreate the table as well.

Comment: actually I've not phpmyadmin there so I want to know a command which I can use through putty

Comment: @Rayan `mysqldump` works on the command line accessed through SSH.

Answer (score 2):

If the dump is going to be very large, you'll probably want to run it in the background, to assure you losing connection to SSH doesn't cause a problem.

Also, you could use nice if it is a live server and don't want to effect its performance too much

```
nohup nice mysqldump -uuser -ppassword [other flags] database tablename > dumpfile.sql
```

You can then use SSH File Transfer to download it to your computer, or use scp to send it to another server:

```
nohup nice scp dumpfile.sql user@IP:/path/ &
```

Then you can load it in to mysql

```
nohup nice mysql -uuser -ppassword database < dumpfile.sql &
```

**Use nohup if its going to take a long time and losing connection could be a problem.  nohup causes to run in background

**Use nice to lower the priority of the process, ie. in case is live server and performance is important.  You should know nice doesn't stop your mysql from being slowed down by a query that takes a long time to finish, so beware.